# How to create a table using ('cache') in yii2 dbcache?

Tags: php, yii2

When I want to use `yii\caching\DbCache` in my yii2 code, I get :

> **Error:** Table "cache" does not exist.

How can I create this table?

**config/web.php:**

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\DbCache',
    ],
```

**controller code:**

```
$cache = Yii::$app->cache;
    $duration = 30;

    if($currency == 'USD')
    {
        // try retrieving $data from cache
        $data = $cache->get('getCurrencyUSD');
        if($data === false)
        {
            $url = 'wsdl file address ...';
            $client = new SoapClient($url);
            $data = $client->getCurrency('USD');
            $cache->set('getCurrencyUSD', $data, $duration);
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Document for use DB cache http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-dbcache.html#$cacheTable-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new migration and add the [following example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-dbcache.html#$cacheTable-detail)

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('{{%cache}}', [
        'id' => $this->char(128)->notNull(),
        'expire' => $this->integer()->null(),
        'data' => 'BLOB',
    ]);

    $this->addPrimaryKey('pk-cache', '{{%cache}}', 'id');
}

public function down()
{
   $this->dropTable('{{%cache}}');
}
```